# How to configure GWT configuration to start up Drools Workbench in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, drools, workbench

I have downloaded drools-wb-6.4.x and kie-wb-common-6.4.x at github, after compiles with maven, I import the two as modules into an empty project. However, the README.MD provided by official that tells how to configure seems  out-of-date I dont know how to correctly configure GWT configuration to start up this project, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run GWT app from Idea, you will have to use so called GWT Super Dev Mode.

[How to get GWT Super Dev Mode to work with IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841301/how-to-get-gwt-super-dev-mode-to-work-with-intellij)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have checked on the box of Use GWT Super Dev Mode.