# How to correctly debug a GWT application with Jetty Runner in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, gwt, jetty

I'm trying to migrate some legacy GWT applications from eclipse to IntelliJ. Oh man, what a nightmare. I've come very near to a dead end with my research. I'm at the point where there is simply no related page or documentation that I have not seen, not to mention the information on this topic is very, very sparse.

My setup is as follows:

- *IntelliJ IDE*
- *GWT 2.9 plugin*
- *Jetty Runner that is using Jetty v11.0.7*

Here are my GWT and Jetty debug configuration settings:[image: GWT Debug Configuration]

[image: Jetty Runner Debug Configuration]

When I navigate to the jetty server URL I always get "**Error 404 Not Found**" message.

[image]
[image]

Now, when I navigate to the "Debug" directory that is specified in the GWT configuration I do see that there is no RSS.html which is a problem but even the "blank.html" is not able to be navigated to. One potential issue is maybe I am somehow not compiling the debuggable version of the GWT application correctly?

[image]

My other guess is that I have to somehow point to an actual .war file. I do have an ant build script that works just fine and generates a .war that works correctly in production. Below is a screenshot of the generated war file as well as the directory used to build the war archive.

[image]

In summation, how do you correctly debug a GWT application in IntelliJ using the GWT configuration with a Jetty Runner server?

I can promptly provide any additional info that I may have left out.

**EDIT**
I would like to add that this [How to get GWT Super Dev Mode to work with IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841301/how-to-get-gwt-super-dev-mode-to-work-with-intellij) question is very similar to what I am asking here and it was never edited with the correct answer, also since this was posted super dev mode was added. It would be great to get a clear solution documented for myself and others. To reiterate the answer needs to achieve these three things,

- Use a Jetty Runner configuration (to enable use of different Jetty versions as there can be a cascade of conflicts depending on your codebase)
- Use a GWT configuration to run a code server with the Jetty Runner instance so debugging is possible.
- Use IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Did you add the GWT and web facet?

Comment: Jetty 11 requires use of Jakarta EE 9 namespace changed libraries, aka "jakarta big bang".  old release versions of GWT will not work with this new of a Servlet spec.  see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66368511/775715

Comment: @ElHoss hey, yes they are both added.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt thanks will take a look into this.